# VBA connect to MySQL database, but select 2 different servers

Tags: vba, mysql-connector

I have had the drivers recently installed on my computer to the latest version, however the database `strConnection` is looking for the previous driver version. If I change this, no one else will be able to run the macros as I am the only one with a different driver.

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

strConnection = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=" & SERVER & _
        ";PORT=3306;DATABASE=" & DB & _
        ";UID=" & UID & ";PWD=" & PWD & ";"
cn.Open strConnection
```

My driver is the 8.2 and if I leave it like this I won't be able to run the macros myself. How can I put both 8.0 and 8.2 there? Otherwise I will need to have the 8.0's installed.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out the installed ODBC driver for MySQL, you can check the ODBC Settings in the registry. The list of available ODBC driver can be found in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI`. Mine looks like this

[image]

As you can see, I have installed 8.2

Now all you have to do is to loop over the keys within that branch and look for the MySQL driver. Unfortunately, access to the registry is not build into VBA, and if you want to loop over keys, you need to use WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation). The syntax is not really intuitive to get the object you need. If you're interested, see for example [Explain VBScript WMI query / impersonationLevel, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963357/explain-vbscript-wmi-query-impersonationlevel-etc)

Once you have that registry object, things are straight forward. You use the method `EnumKey` to get an array of subkey names and simply loop over that array to look for an entry for MySQL.
(Disclaimer: Code bases on what I found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-need-a-loop-go-look-through-registry-help-needed.338531/))

```
Function getMySQLDriverName() As String
    Const regCategory = &H80000002 ' HKEY_lOCAL_MACHINE
    Const regKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI"
    
    Dim reg As Object, subKeys
    Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    reg.EnumKey regCategory, regKeyPath, subKeys
    
    Dim driver As String, i As Long
    For i = LBound(subKeys) To UBound(subKeys)
        driver = subKeys(i)
        If Left(driver, 5) = "MySQL" And InStr(driver, "Unicode") > 0 Then
            getMySQLDriverName = driver
            Debug.Print driver
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

And your code could look like

```
Dim driverName As String
driverName = getMySQLDriverName
If driverName = "" Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, it seems you don't have a MySQL driver installed"
    Exit Sub
End If

strConnection = "Driver={" & driverName & "};SERVER=" & SERVER & _
    ";PORT=3306;DATABASE=" & Db & _
    ";UID=" & UID & ";PWD=" & PWD & ";"

cn.Open strConnection
```

Some remarks:

- I have tested the code to fetch the driver name, but not the code that connects to the database as I currently have no MySQL database available.
- I don't know if it is a thing, but if you are using 32bit drivers on a 64bit Windows, you probably need to use `SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI`
- If you have multiple drivers for MySQL installed in parallel, the function will return the first one (which might be the oldest). You need to improve the function to figure out the newest if that's not okay for you
- A personal advice: Forget about wrongly understood hungarian notation for variable names and switch to early binding for the ADODB connection object.